# Как в UMI CMS можно вручную добавлять комментарий через админку?

Tags: cms, php, umi

Здравствуйте

Как в UMI CMS можно вручную добавлять комментарий через админку?
Есть такая возможность там? И, если нету, то как её можно добавить?

Answer (score 1):

Добавлять свои комментарии через модуль "Комментарии" похоже нельзя. Но можно копировать комментарии в модуле "Структура" и редактировать их.